# How can we add a "useful resources" to the help center?

Tags: discussion, support, help-center

I've visited the [help-center](https://buddhism.stackexchange.com/help) of one the sites, and noticed a "useful resources" section:

> [image]

I'm surprised to see it, since I don't see it in the help center of other sites.

So, how can we have such section in other site? Can a community (say [Hinduism](http://hinduism.stackexchange.com)) decide and write such stuff (if worthy to provide according to the type of site) on help-center?

Comment: Wow!  That is one really awesome wiki they've got there. :)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The area between the search box and "Find out more about…" is editable by moderators, which is what you see in the linked page.

This means that the community can indeed decide to write such stuff and the moderators edit into that space.

This is entirely up to the community to do.

Comment: Well, surprised only few sites have it. Can any moderator just change it, or does it go through some kind of review?

Comment: @ShadowWizard - since it is open to moderators only, no review. We do keep a history (like all posts).

Comment: As for why it isn't used more... hidden feature?

Comment: Huh, good point. Well, guess OP here can ask in the per site meta of Hinduism or in its chat room.

Comment: This was originally implement for [Japanese SO](http://ja.stackoverflow.com/help). Our help center is massive, and rather than bombard people with a dozen articles to read, I wanted to do a more original SO FAQ style 1-page help. So we got this section added. I didn't realize it had been enabled on all the other sites. My guess is that we haven't documented it anywhere (*until now!*), which is why most sites haven't done anything with it.