# Odd "edit" link has appeared in the help center

Tags: bug, moderator-tools, help-center

If you visit a site's `/help` page as a moderator, you now have a weird "edit" link:

[image: screenshot of the help center showing the edit link]

Clicking on it brings up an inline editor box which lets me add text that appears just above the link:

[image: screenshot showing added text]

That doesn't seem to be doing anything useful, so I assume the edit button is a bug. Is it actually a bug or are we supposed to use this space to add a header to our help center or something? I admit I don't really see much point to it, if so. Am I missing something?

Comment: https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/279848/260388

Comment: https://hardwarerecs.stackexchange.com/help for an example of a site that uses this